# Graph with n vertices and with degree n-1 for every vertex is connected

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, induction

Do you think that this induction proof is sufficient? If not, why? Thank you

Let us prove the claim via induction.

Let us have a graph $G=(V,E)$ such that $|V(G)| = n $ and $\forall v \in V(G): \deg(v) = \delta = n-1
$.
**Base case:** Let us have $n=1$, then $\delta = 1-1=0$. This is an isolated vertex that is a connected component by itself. Trivially it holds. 
**IH and step-case:** Assume that claim holds $\forall n \geq 1$. Prove for $n+1$
Let us have $G' = (V',E')$ such that $|V'(G')| = n+1$. Let us remove a vertex $v\in V'(G')$, since $\deg(v) = \delta = n-1$, we determine graph is connected by the $IH$. Let us add back v into G', then $\deg(v) = (n+1)-1 = n$. Since all the vertices were connected to each other, and this vertex is connected to $n$ vertices, therefore it must be the case that new graph with $n+1$ vertices is also connected.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the induction hypothesis means that the claim holds for all $k \le n$. If the claim would hold for all $n \ge 1$, you would have already proven the theorem.

In your proof, $\deg(v) = n$, which invalidates it. Instead, just note that if $G$ is a graph such that every vertex in it has degree $n-1$, then each vertex is connected to every other vertex.

Comment: Oh yea I think I see, do we need to use strong induction for this proof by the way ? Or we are suppose to use normal induction. I just realized that I used strong induction kinda unintentionally.

Comment: You don't need induction at all. Every vertex is connected to every other vertex. You are dealing with a complete graph here.

Comment: hmm so I can prove it with a direct proof as well, I see. I would be very happy if you can show me an induction proof of this as well however, I have been trying to improve my induction skills on graphs. Thanks !